# How to change scale value in visAD libraray?

Tags: java, scale, visad

I am new to visAD library. I am trying to plot a 'lowerTerrain.nc' file in visAD.

But its longitude(-180 to +180) and latitude(-80 to +80) ranges are displayed in by default values, which are -150 to +150 for longitude range(X axis) and -90 to +90 in latitude range(Y Axis).

I have tried this:

```
LatLonLines longLine=new latLonLines(RealType.Longitude,-180.0f,180.0f,30.0f);
longLine.setVisible(true);
```

But I don't know how to add this longLine object on the display.

REFERENCE:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/idv/docs/javadoc/ucar/visad/display/LatLonLines.html

Comment: I have tried to clean the text, but I can't understand what do you mean by " are displayed in by default values". Please, correct the phrase. And don't mix range and scale. Especially when you talk on cartography. SCALE is something absolutely different. Correct the title yourself, please.

Answer (score 1):

@Gangus: Thank you for your remark.

The range for longitude is -180 to 180 which i want to show on scale line as two end values.
But by default, the scale shows -150 to +150 (at correct place,means where +- 150 lies).

In programming, to view the line(X-Axis) they use "Scale". For Eg:

```
GraphicsModeControl dispGMC = (GraphicsModeControl)  display.getGraphicsModeControl();
dispGMC.setScaleEnable(true);
```

And as I want changes in the way the values in my scale (related to longitude) looks , I keep this title.

Here, I have set the Range,which is not an issue:

```
ScalarMap lonMap=new ScalarMap(RealType.Longitude, Display.XAxis)
lonMap.setRange(-180.0f, +180.0f);
```

So, my question is I have used  this:

```
LatLonLines longLine=new latLonLines(RealType.Longitude,-180.0f,180.0f,30.0f);
longLine.setVisible(true);
```

And how to reflect this to the Display.

Answer (score 0):

I have used AxisScale for that and it perfectly works...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).